# For Loop: Leap year

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

I'm trying to write a program that displays ten leap years per line until the year 2100.

The code I have so far is this:

```
public class leapYear {
public static void main (String args[]){
    int leapYear = 2001; // initialize leapYear variable to 2001

    if (leapYear <= 2100){
        for (int x = 0; x <= 10; x++){ // print ten leap years per line
            System.out.print(leapYear + " ");
            leapYear = leapYear + 4;
        }// end of for loop
        System.out.println(" ");
        int x = 0;
    } // end of if statement

}// end of main method
```

}// end of class

The output I get from the code is:

```
2001 2005 2009 2013 2017 2021 2025 2029 2033 2037 2041
```

I'm having trouble finding a condition that will allow me to print the next series of leapYears on the following lines. Any guidance would be appreciate.

Comment: FWIW - 2001 wasn't a leap year, but 2000 was.

Comment: Those are not leap years, by the way. 2000 is a leap year. 2001 is not. Additionally, 2100 is NOT a leap year per [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year).

Comment: You can use [`GregorianCalendar.isLeapYear()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) to determine if a year is or is not a leap year.

Comment: If you want to improve your leapyear program, you should make a for loop to go over all the years you want to check (say 2001 through 2099) and test each year to see if it's a leap year.  Right now you're picking a starting year and adding 4 to it over and over.  If you had to increase the number of years to say, 2500, your program would show incorrect years.  Leap year is NOT just every 4 years!  Years divisible by 100 like 1900 or 2100 are **not** leap years, but years divisible by 400 **are** leap years.  It's easier to test each year then to guess - you'll always get it right.

Comment: @doublesharp You got the point. And BTW **[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year)** can sometimes be a good source of information. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public static void main (String args[]){
    int leapYear = 2001; // initialize leapYear variable to 2001

    while (leapYear <= 2100){
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++){ // print ten leap years per line
            if (leapYear > 2100){ // if leapYear is over 2100, stop printing
                break;
            }
            System.out.print(leapYear + " ");
            leapYear = leapYear + 4;
        }// end of for loop
        System.out.println(" ");
        int x = 0;
    } // end of if statement

}// end of main method
```

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. please provide some explanation

Answer (score 1):

Change the `if(leapYear <= 2100)` line to `while(leapYear <= 2100)`.

The if statement will only execute once, meaning you print out 10 dates. A while loop will execute as many times as it takes for leapYear to be greater than 2100.

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. please provide more info

Comment: Nit pick, 2100 isn't a leap year, so use < 2100.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently using an `if`statement to check whether or not you want to print something (`if (leapYear <= 2100)`). However, after your for-loop you want to check again whether there are still more leap years to print before reaching the year `2100`. This can be accomplished by using a `while`loop instead, i.e. `while(leapYear < 2100)`.  (As 2100 is not a leap year, see below)

Additionally, it should be noted that 2004 is a better starting place for leap-years and 2100 is not a leap year (wheareas 2000 was). See the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year) for more information.

Second note unrelated to your problem, you can also use `System.out.println();` (so without an argument) to print the newline you are after.

Third and final, the line `int x = 0;` is not necessary as the counter `x` in your `for`loop no longer exists outside of that loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your If statement is whats giving you the trouble, it only executes once. You need something like a while loop, or you could use a for loop like so,

```
                for (int leapYear = 2001; leapYear <= 2100; leapYear += 4) {
                    if((leapYear - 1) % 40 == 0) {
                        System.out.println(" ");
                    }
                    System.out.print(leapYear + " ");
                }
```

However I would like to point out that none of the years you print out are leap years. leap years are those divisible by 4 except when divisible by 100 except when also divisible by 400 (ie 2000 was a leap year 2004 was and 2100 won't be but 2400 will be) super confusing you may want to check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year) out on leap years.

Good luck!

Comment: The modulo 40 allows for 10 leap years to be printed on a single line, and if its modulo 40 (ie 10 leap years have passed) it should start a new line. Although it should be noted that this doesn't account for the non leap years every 100 years. instead a count should be put in and every 10 times you print out a leap year it should add a new line

Answer (score 1):

You asked how to have 10 leap years print per line.
To accomplish this, simply change:

`if (leapYear <= 2100) {`

To:

`while (leapYear <= 2100) {`

With the full working and tested example here:

```
public class LeapYear {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int leapYear = 2001; // initialize leapYear variable to 2001

        while (leapYear <= 2100) { // a simple change of "If" to "While" here
                                    // will do the trick
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
                System.out.print(leapYear + " "); // print ten leap years per
                                                    // line
                leapYear = leapYear + 4;
            }
            System.out.println();
        } // end of while loop
    } // end of main method
}// end of class
```

That being said, I would recommend some of the things that have already been mentioned.

1 - There are some logic errors in your code that will incorrectly name some years leap years. See [here](http://www.timeanddate.com/date/leapyear.html) for more information on Leap Years.
2 - If you try my example, you'll also notice that the leap years are shown past 2100. You'll need to figure out a way to correctly structure your code if you don't want the numbers to be displayed past 2100.
3 - I would strongly recommend you take a look at the [GregorianCalendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) class, as it will simplify your code to check for a leap year. However, if you are doing this to learn or for a school assignment, I would recommend looking at the link under number 1.
4 - More of an aside, but in your code you have:
`leapYear = leapYear + 4`
This can be simplified to:
`leapYear += 4`

Hopefully this helps clarify things for you.

Answer (score 0):

Providing the correct implementation for leap year:

```
public void main(String[] args) {
    for(int year = 2001 ; year <= 2100 ; ++year) {
        if(isLeapYear(year)) {
            System.out.println(year);
        }
    }
}

public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    if (year % 4 != 0) {
        return false;
    } else if (year % 400 == 0) {
        return true;
    } else if (year % 100 == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: good god, it seems you are around here enough to know that it is better to provide some explantion to help the op  **not doing the homework for the op**

Comment: I mean who are you? You would have answered differently? Great! Every good input is welcome. Sorry for providing some extra in my answer while others have already answered the OP.

Comment: it is what it is. I cannot change people. :)